# bash variable containing spaces expanded in single quotes

Tags: shell

I have a script which calls make like this (simplified)

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f one.source ]]
then
    make one CPPFLAGS='-DONE -DTWO -DTHREE'
fi

if [[ -f two.source ]]
then
    make two CPPFLAGS='-DONE -DTWO -DTHREE'
fi
```

The list of defines is getting long, and I'd like to avoid having to keep the two command lines in sync. I'd like to define a variable and use it in both commands. I tried

```
DEFINES='-DONE -DTWO -DTHREE'

DD="CPPFLAGS='"
DD+=$DEFINES
DD+="'"
```

With this,

```
echo $DD
CPPFLAGS='-DONE -DTWO -DTHREE'
```

seems to do what I want, but

```
make one $DD
```

fails with

```
make one 'CPPFLAGS='\''-DONE' -DTWO '-DTHREE'\'''
make: invalid option -- 'D'
make: invalid option -- 'T'
make: invalid option -- 'D'
make: invalid option -- 'T'
make: invalid option -- 'H'
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
```

Comment: Quick response whilst AFK: How about leaving the expansion to `make` rather than doing it in the shell?  Have your Makefile reference/manipulate the envariable value with `$(DD)`?  (I'll try for a more complete response later, but here's an idea until then..)

Comment: Sadly, my makefiles are generated and there's no point in editing them because they may be overwritten at any time.

Comment: For some background, see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050); quotes-that-are-data do not substitute for missing quotes-that-are-syntax. Granted, `make` can easily transform generate syntax by concatenating data onto a string it passes as code, but from a security perspective that's a bug, not a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not quote yourself. Use `printf "%q"` or `@Q` expansion.

Use bash arrays.

```
defines=(
   -DONE
   -DTWO
   -DTHREE
)
make_args=(
   "CPPFLAGS=${defines[*]@Q}"
)
make one "${make_args[@]}"
```

> but

`$DD` is not quoted, so it undergoes word splitting expansion, which splits it on spaces.

Check your script with shellcheck.

Make is an old grandpa. Consider using newer build system, like CMake.

Comment: CMake isn't exactly new :) and it generates makefiles, so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `it generates makefiles, so it doesn't make a difference` It generates makefiles, so it means, that cmake takes care of properly quoting your CPPFLAGS. The functionality you are searching for is part of cmake already. Thus the reference.

Comment: Would this be doable in ksh?

Comment: I know nothing about ksh, never used it. In posix, use `printf "%q "`.